# Next.js 14.1 Dev Mode compilation extremely slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've recently upgraded my Next.js project to version 14.1, excited about the new features and improvements. However, I've noticed a significant slowdown in compilation times while running the project in development mode (next dev). It's taking noticeably longer than before, which impacts my workflow productivity.

Has anyone else encountered this issue with Next.js 14.1 in development mode? If so, are there any known fixes or optimizations that can help speed up the compilation process?

Here are a few details about my setup:

```
Next.js version: 14.1
Node.js version: node-v20.11.0-x64
Operating system: Win 10
```

I've tried some basic troubleshooting steps like clearing caches and ensuring my dependencies are up to date, but the issue persists.

Comment: I haven't seen this behaviour but you could try using turbo `next dev --turbo` it is much faster

Comment: I saw the same problem posted on GitHub. (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48748)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this issue for a while. You can try adding a new script in the package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "fast": "next dev --turbo",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
},
```

then use this command:

```
npm run fast
```

It is in beta (experimental) mode but it is much faster. Here's the [official documentation link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/turbo).